# Code for HY Estimator

Tags: high-frequency, high-frequency-estimators

Does anyone here has a code for [HY estimator](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2225753), preferably in python?

I have written a very basic code in python but my results are weird. When I run it for two liquid assets traded on two different exchanges simultaneously, I get a correlation of only 0.8% and a lead/analysis shows a kink at 1-sec. It is the same asset trading in two places so the correlation has to be fairly significant and 1-sec of lead/lag is very very unlikely. I was wondering if someone can help or share a few pointers?

I know of the yuima library in R which implements this, but my knowledge of R minimal and hence looking for some help.

Comment: What is the HY estimator? You could please bring more details on that (reference to the page or equation in the quoted paper) as I could not find any reference of "HY" in the paper...

Comment: HY estimator is Hayashi-Yoshida estimator, used to find correlation between asynchronous time series data. I've updated the link with an explicit implementation of the paper

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately for you (but maybe helpful to others) I can only refer to R packages.

The R package high-frequency ([link](https://cran.r-project.org/package=highfrequency)) provides `rHYCov`.  The synchrony package ([link](https://cran.r-project.org/package=synchrony)) provides a whole plethora of methods for temporal, spatial and spatio-temporal statistics.

Furthermore, I would personally advise against HY for its boundary artefacts and instead use something more robust like cross-correlation with the Bjornstad-Falck kernel.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, I will look in to Bjornstad-Falck kernel. In the meantime, can you tell me what kind of numbers do you get/expect for correlation for same assets that trade on different venues at the same time

Comment: I'm doing 4-fold oversampling, so if the mean arrival time is 100 ms, I'm looking for leads/lags with 25 ms resolution, I then get a correlation of about 0.95 to 0.99 on the main lag, 0.90 to 0.92 on the first side lags, 0.40 to 0.60 on the second side lags.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that Bjornstad-Falck is quite a bit slower, just in case you need it for low-latency HFT.

Comment: @hroptatyr, any good reference to cross-correlation with the Bjornstad-Falck kernel (or code package)? Or the reason why not to use HY. Thanks